# renderView() issue for admin controller in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I creates a new custom module with the following code, It displays a list view in back office.

```
class AdminTestController extends ModuleAdminController {
    public $bootstrap = true;

    public function __construct() {
        $this - > table = 'test';
        $this - > className = 'TestData';
        $this - > lang = false;
        $this - > deleted = false;
        $this - > addRowAction('edit');
        $this - > addRowAction('view');


        $this - > fields_list = array(
            'id_test' => array(
                'title' => $this - > l('ID'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 25
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'title' => $this - > l('Name'),
                'width' => 'auto',
            )
        );

        $this - > bulk_actions = array(
            'delete' => array(
                'text' => $this - > l('Delete selected'),
                'confirm' => $this - > l('Delete selected items?')
            )
        );

        $this - > context = Context::getContext();

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function renderForm() {
        /** @var Test $obj */
        if (!($obj = $this - > loadObject(true))) {
            return;
        }

        $this - > fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this - > l('TEST')
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this - > l('Name'),
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'size' => 33,
                    'required' => true
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this - > l(' Save '),
                'class' => 'button pull-right'
            )
        );

        return parent::renderForm();
    }

    public function renderView() {
        /** @var Test $test */
        if (!($test = $this - > loadObject())) {
            return;
        }

        $data = Config::getDataForm(Tools::getValue('id_test'));
        // var_dump($data);

        $this - > tpl_view_vars = array(
            'id_test' => $data['id_test'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
        );

        return parent::renderView();
    }
}
```

In which I have a renderView() function to show the particular list values in new page.

But I get following error on the view page,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in /var/www/html/prestashop/modules/test/controllers/admin/AdminTestController.php on line 145
```

I am new to prestashop. I am using prestashop 1.6

Please help me someone to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The correct is

```
$data = Tools::getValue('id_test');
```

The "Config" is not a class in prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line in your code:

```
$data = Config::getDataForm(Tools::getValue('id_test'));
```

The function that you are calling here (i.e. getDataForm()) doesn't exist in PrestaShop, even the Config class doesn't exist as well.

It is not possible why you are using this line of code, but you should remove the call to getDataForm() function in this line.